# Exception Android Google Cloud messaging register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When I'm trying to register my app device to the server, I'm getting this error:
I have imported the gogole-play-services_lib like an application and added this library in my application in the Properties->Android->Add

```
    12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362): Process: com.appehour.jdm, PID: 29362
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:478)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:467)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.d(Unknown Source)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.b(Unknown Source)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at com.appehour.jdm.TestPush$registerInBackground.doInBackground(TestPush.java:172)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at com.appehour.jdm.TestPush$registerInBackground.doInBackground(TestPush.java:1)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-10 16:00:03.026: E/AndroidRuntime(29362):    ... 4 more
```

And this is my code in background:

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }

                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                Log.d(TAG_LOGS, "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid);

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                Log.e(TAG_LOGS, "Error :" + ex.getMessage());
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }
     }
```

I don't know how resolve it. Thank's you.

Comment: are you by any chance testing on an emulator ?

Comment: i'm testing on Nexus 4, version 4.4.2

Comment: I have the same device with same OS level, GAE is working just fine on my end, make sure you have the latest library (Google Play Service) 13. and you have the latest android SDK tools + build/Platform.

if that didn't work submit a bug to android project (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list)

Comment: I have the latest library (Google Play Service) 13. and  the latest android SDK tools + build/Platform

Comment: According to this issue (which seems to be the same) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820079/google-cloud-messaging-register-fails Passing the ApplicationContext to GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance() fixes the problem.

Answer (score 6):

This one is very tricky. Verify that

```
GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
```

is not running with a null context. It was the case for me and I got exactly the error that you described. After I fixed my context (I forgot mContext=ctx in my helper class constructor) the error disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Another situation that this error happens is when google play services is not installed on device. For example on genymotion VDs and cyanogenmod (w/o google apps installed) devices.

Answer (score 0):

I had:

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
```

replaced it with:

```
gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

That fixed it.