# Unable to register Android token with API level 16

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app that uses Lollipop and works OK. I wanted to add support for prior versions of Android. I set a device using API level 16, but for some reason I keep getting NullPointerException on the following command:

```
String token = gcm.register(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
```

Of course that "gcm" is not null.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

### EDIT:

I did some changes and raised API level to 17. The code looks like that now:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
String token = instanceID.getToken(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

Still, it doesn't pass the command:

```
instanceID.getToken
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting the gcm per this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820079/google-cloud-messaging-register-fails

Comment: I'd recommend that you switch to using InstanceID, its now the recommended way for Android clients to register. Check step 5 in this doc:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

Comment: Thanks, I did switch to InstanceID. Now my app doesn't crash, but it also doesn't run any of the code after the line: InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context). I also tried switching to API level 17. What am I doing wrong? On API 22 all seem seems to be working correct.

Comment: Sorry, it fails running this command: String token = instanceID.getToken(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I noticed the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE
```

I understood that the problem was related with the fact that Google Play was not installed on my emulator. I have no idea why Google didn't decide to automatically included it in older emulators.

I solved the problem by:

- Switching to Genymotion emulator which is much faster.
- Installing Google Play on Genymotion emulator:

  - Download proper Google Play zip file which can be found on the net (there is a version for eacj api level).
  - Drag & Drop the file on Genymotion emulator.
  - Follow the installation steps and restart.

After taking these actions I was no longer getting this exception.